# How to update the field of Ojbect in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

When I use VBA, I want to update an object's field by function, but I don't know how to do that.

an any one give me some advice?

```
Type MyObject
    a as String
    b as Boolean
End Type

'update function
Sub update(ByVal o as MyObject, key as String, value as string)
    o.key = value 'this is what I want to do!
End sub
```

I don't know very much about VBA, is this possible?

Comment: I would also strongly caution calling a `type` something like `MyObject` Objects and Types are two specific things. It's much easier to code down the line when your type name is something that is more descriptive to it's functionality or purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set any value of a field named `key`, because such key does not exist in the definiton of `MyObject`. What you can do is something like this:

```
o.a = key
o.b = value
```

**EDIT**

To specify which field you want update, you can add a conditional statement to you function.

```
If key = "a" Then
    o.a = value
Else
    o.b = value
End If
```

I'm afraid you cannot loop through all fields in a type, because VBA does not support reflection.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but the purpose of the function is when function is called,I don't know will a be updated or will b be updated,so I want to call the function like " update(myObject,"a","valueofA") or update(myObject,"b","true")

Comment: Yes! that is right! I know what should I do now! thanks very much!